# react dynamic render with number

Tags: reactjs

my `page.js`

```
class R1 extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="r1">
                <h1>level1</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
class R2 extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="r2">
                <h1>level2</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

my `main.js`

```
important * as Page from './page';
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="r1">
                <Page.R+level/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Skip getInitialState,
I want to dynamic render with level. 
I try `React.renderComponent(<Page.R+this.state.level />, document.body);`

It's not working with failed: SyntaxError

Is there more easily way? or is dynamic render available?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`main.js` can be modified like this to achieve what you want

```
import * as Page from './page';
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
  const level = 2;
    return (
      <div className="r1">

        {/*You use loop over list to get value of level and render all the pages*/}

        {React.createElement(Page[`R${level}`], null)} 

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`Page` is an object and we are trying to access the pages and rendering the component name which is in string type.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you are exporting your Components so there is an assumption here, generally it is convention to put them in different files.

You can render in your parent component using an if statement inside JSX like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var renderPage;
    if (something) {
      renderPage = <PageOne />;
    } else {
      renderPage = <PageTwo />;
    }
    return (
      <div>
       {renderPage}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```